# error while editing views

Tags: views, entities, javascript, 8

When I'm editing a view and I click on one of the fields to edit them I get a javascript error

[image: fields in view editor]

Error: TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function
Source File: http://drupal.mydomainname.ca/misc/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js?v=1.8.7
Line: 13

When I click Apply or Cancel on the configuration dialog I get taken to a page with nothing but a JSON string on it at this url

http://drupal.mydomainname.ca/admin/structure/views/ajax/config-item/home_page_slider/block/field/field_image

Anyone else have this error or know what might cause it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Update has some problems with v1.8.7 currently (related to the version of jQuery UI included); downgrading to v1.7 should fix the problem.

See these issues on D.o for more information:

- [Suddenly stopped working - TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function](http://drupal.org/node/1934310)
- [Update jQuery UI to 1.8.24](http://drupal.org/node/1847900)

The reason your View isn't working is simply that the Javascript error is preventing the relevant events from being attached to the elements. So when you click a link, instead of Views loading the JSON via AJAX and processing it, you're instead forwarded to the JSON page itself.