# When I try to modify a view, I get a screen full of odd text

Tags: 7, views

I have just installed views, and every time I attempt to change a setting (or cancel) I receive a white screen with paragraphs of strange info:

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/forms\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"blogon_responsive_theme","theme_token":"cD6VFX2j18jV0Gu1-xq10ADeBk_yP4V57yKYNYhNnhs"}},"merge":true},{"command":"viewsDismissForm"},{"command":"viewsShowButtons"},{"command":"viewsTriggerPreview"},{"command":"insert","method":"html","selector":"#views-tab-page","data":"\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-details\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-top\u0022 class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-actions views-ui-display-tab-bucket clearfix\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-button ctools-dropbutton\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-
```

CAn anyone tell me whats wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: See this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73187/cannot-edit-my-views-i-get-a-json-string/73300#73300 Sounds like it's a jQuery version problem to me.

Comment: It sounds like the problem I was having, but installing jQuery update and setting the admin version to 1.5 did not fix the problem.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was not the view I was using, it was the theme. the blogon-responsive-theme breaks views

Comment: This issue is also caused by not having an update in ctools

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of ctools (production) on Friday (April 5).  Would the update be in that one or in the dev version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a JQuery AJAX failure.  Several different things could be causing this.  You will probably need to research the current active theme and any modules that you are using in or around that view (especially ones that use AJAX) to see if they have a history of AJAX related failures (and related fixes or patches.)  A few things to try:

- Enable, disable or change the settings within the [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module (some versions of jquery are not compatible with some modules.)
- Change the theme used on admin pages to a generic theme (included in the Drupal download)

Answer (score 0):

Neither of Hoytman's suggestions fixed the issue for me. The only way I could get around it was by going to /admin/structure/views/settings/advanced and enabling the "Disable JavaScript with Views" option.