# Drupal 7 + Data (External) + Views - Can't Add Relationship [White Screen + JSON]

Tags: views, database

I can't add relationships to Views generated by the Data module.

I have some external (related) tables I need to patch together for viewing, and linking from other parts of the site.

I get a white screen, with a JSON-style dump of state.

As per [Cannot edit my views.. I get a JSON string?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73187/cannot-edit-my-views-i-get-a-json-string) I've got jQuery Update installed and tried:

- using a different version of jQuery for the admin (v1.5) [same result]
- disabling jQuery Update entirely [same result]
- disabling JavaScript for Views editing (Structure > Views > Settings > Advanced) [no error, but no relationship editing, just back to main View edit screen]
- switching the theme for editing Views (Bartik and Seven) [same result]

NOTE: Also confirmed no PHP errors present, have cleared caches after each settings change, etc.

So, since the tables are related (actually coming from another database), I figured I'd experiment with Foreign Keys. I understand that Drupal doesn't (or didn't) natively honour them (due to breaking integrity in some cases), but I figured it might give Schema the push it needed to associate the related tables.

Foreign Keys didn't work either (in fact, now I can't update adopted tables and or set Joins).

The last option I can see is to use a programmatic approach via a custom module using **hook_views_data** (something like [How do I display an external database data?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/how-do-i-display-an-external-database-data/))

Any confirmation, suggestions, etc.?

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: I bailed on this, having opted to go a different route (creating a custom module, doing db_query and using hook_menu + hook_theme to get the same results). In the event that somebody comes up with something clever, insightful, etc. I'll leave this open for a bit longer.

Comment: If you are using the efq_views module, it does not currently support relationships.