# How to prevent showing background code in Drupal 7 admin?

Tags: debugging

I am seeing the following screen when i am saving or updating a node in drupal 7 admin.

I am using Drupal 7 with Seven theme.I am seeing the following texts in white screen.To get the actual i need to click back button.

> [ {"command":"settings", "settings":{"basePath":"\u002F",
>   "pathPrefix":"", "ajaxPageState":{"theme":"nbiz_train",
>   "theme_token":"BVOiHIMf2BoQgMAltQtiv_GRDGBYoFOGNn3hJ8eJRxw"},
>   "colorbox":{"opacity":"0.85", "current":"{current} of {total}",
>   "previous":"« Prev", "next":"Next »", "close":"Close",
>   "maxWidth":"98%", "maxHeight":"98%", "fixed":true,
>   "mobiledetect":true, "mobiledevicewidth":"480px"}}, "merge":true} ]

How can i remove this error?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may be related to (caused by) [JQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update), similar to what is described in "[Cannot edit my views.. I get a JSON string?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73187)".

Maybe you want to (temporary) try any of these potential work arounds:

- Disable or change the settings within [JQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) (to see if it solves the issue).
- Change the admin theme to any theme included in the Drupal version you downloaded.